# Wamp Server Alias syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Am having this problem when I edit my "httpd.conf" file. Basically what the issue is, starts whenever i edit my "httpd.conf" file. particularly the "alias" section of the http.conf file.

Am trying to create a direct alias to a folder i created in my root drive c:\ in windows.

Whenever i add this lines of code below into the alias section

```
    <IfModule alias_module>
    # ...
    # Configure the tshirtshop alias
    Alias /tshirtshop/ "C:/tshirtshop/"
    Alias /tshirtshop "C:/tshirtshop"
    </IfModule>

 <Directory "C:/tshirtshop">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

My Wamps server never turns green again. Tried all the trick in the book, starting from disabling anything that might be making use of the port 80, to setting a new port for my Apache server to use, none seem to work.

I went further into my event viewer to see my error log, that was when i saw the log for Apache, after opening it to review, i saw a syntax error, so i knew the syntax for the alias was so wrong. took out all the lines above i inserted,and viola, its turns green again and everything works fine.

Now i still want to create the alias to the folder in my root drive, but don't know what is really wrong in the syntax used above.

Would appreciate if someone can go through the line of codes and tell me what am doing wrong, or a possible right syntax to use an alias.

Hope to read from someone pretty soon.

Regards

Comment: Have you checked the Apache error log under `wamp/logs/apache_error.log`

Comment: yeah, seem to have done that. can paste it in here if you so request. It obvious its a syntax error. if i can get that right, then am so sure its gonna work!

Comment: i finally solved the error since i didn't get the desired answer on time. so would post it in here in case someone else has the same issue, he/she can refer to this thread. So basically what was the cause of the syntax error was just a wrong placement of each line of code. The "alias" part of the code should go to the alias, and the directory line should be placed in the directory section of the httpd.conf. That did the trick and my Wamp server ran perfectly and i was even able access it via my browser.